# Have we ever seen Odo impersonate another humanoid?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Odo, the security chief on *Deep Space Nine*, is a shapeshifter and seemingly adept at impersonating furniture, rats and other small animals.

He does make a comment about finding it difficult to impersonate a Bajoran nose. Do we ever see him attempt (however successfully) to impersonate another humanoid besides his own regular appearance?

Comment: He impersonate the female changeling. Does that count?

Comment: he kind of morphs into an amalgamation of Kurzon Dax and himself [Odo] when he does the Zhian'tara with Jadzia Dax

Comment: @Valorum I don’t remember that, but I guess so.

Comment: @NKCampbell yes, good point. I’d forgotten that.

Comment: and, while not shapeshifting, strictly speaking, he impersonates a Klingon (while he is in his 'solid punishment' phase)

Comment: @NKCampbell ha ha, not what I was thinking of.

Comment: :) I know - but - it would be a valid answer to the question as worded currently ;)

Comment: @NKCampbell - Are you posting that as an answer?

Comment: @Valorum - nah, I don't think it fits the spirit of the question. I was just being pedantic :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Odo impersonates the female Changeling in *[DS9: Tacking into the Wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacking_into_the_Wind)*

[image]

---

Moving down the scale, we see him impersonate a Klingon Warrior named Kodrak in [DS9: Apocalypse Rising](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Apocalypse_Rising_(episode)). As has been pointed out in comments, this was *a surgical alteration performed by Bashir* (on Odo stuck in human form) rather than a *shapeshift*.

[image]

And he impersonates a 'generic Cardassian face' in [*DS9: The Courageous, Book 2 of the Rebels Trilogy*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Courageous). It should be noted that although he intends to hide his face behind a mask, it seems to pass casual examination without it.

> Odo himself had suggested the ruse: he had been practicing shapeshifting to a Cardassian since DS9 was Terok Nor. His facial features hidden behind a mask, he could pass cursory muster as a "generic Cardassian." So long as they moved fast and the sentries were not particularly alert, there should be no alarm, thought Sisko.
>
> ...
>
> It occurred to me," said Quark, with a bitter glare in the direction of Odo, still shapeshifted into a Cardassian visage, "that the Cardassians would never believe that the--the Natives would have the initiative to steal a skimmer.

Comment: by defintion, the Founders aren't humanoid though, so is this accurate for the question as asked?

Comment: @NKCampbell - Bearing in mind that I've spent the last few weeks fielding complaints from people because I called the T-1000 'non-humanoid' just because it's got two heads and four arms, I'm really in no mood to open up that can of worms again

Comment: @NKCampbell The Founders may not be humanoid per se, but they take humanoid form when interacting with other races, hence this is a valid answer and within the scope of the OP's question in my opinion.

Comment: Though it does sort of miss the POINT of the question, IMHO, because the Founders, IIRC, essentially look the way they do because they decided to look like ODO (more or less).  Therefore that Odo once impersonated one seems like no special feat of his shapeshifting... it was just making a minor variation.  Impersonating a specific humanoid that DOESN'T look Odo-ish seems a more interesting question, and although the answer's not wrong to be complete it should address whether he's done anyone else besides people who look like him.  IMHO anyway.

Comment: @starpilotsix It's hard to prove a negative from primary sources but, according to [Trek Core](http://ds9.trekcore.com/castcrew/pages/odo.html), this is as good as you get. "in this episode, Odo imitated the Female Changeling; the only time we ever saw him impersonate a specific sentient being."